# KeyStore "unsupported protection parameter"

Tags: java, android, cryptography, android-keystore

I'm trying to store a SecretKey in the Android KeyStore, and I'm even directly following the documentation found here: [KeyProtection: AES Key for Encryption / Description in GCM Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyProtection#example:-aes-key-for-encryptiondecryption-in-gcm-mode), which still doesn't work.

I seem to get the following exception when I run this:

> java.security.KeyStoreException: unsupported protection parameter

This exception is specifically raised when I call `keyStore.setEntry(...)`.

I'm running Android 10 on a Samsung Galaxy S10, if that makes any difference.

```java
@RequiresApi(23)
private static KeyStore.ProtectionParameter getProtectionParameter() {
    return new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build();
}

@RequiresApi(23)
private static SecretKey getSecretKey() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(null);

    if (keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
        final KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore
                .getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
        return secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
    }

    final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build();

    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    SecretKey k = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    keyStore.setEntry(
        KEY_ALIAS,
        new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(k),
        getProtectionParameter()
    );

    return getSecretKey();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the issue I had was in my `KeyStore.getInstance` and `KeyGenerator.getInstance` lines. One of them was using `KeyStore.getDefaultType()` where as the other one was using `AndroidKeyStore`. Changing this got rid of the `unsupported protection parameter` issue.

Additionally, after fixing that I ran into an issue with updating the Protection Parameter.

It turns out, that the following section of the code is incorrect

```java
SecretKey k = keyGenerator.generateKey();

keyStore.setEntry(
    KEY_ALIAS,
    new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(k),
    getProtectionParameter()
);
```

It tries to insert the key into the keystore twice, since `generateKey()` already inserts it into the KeyStore.

The fully working code would look like this

```java
@RequiresApi(23)
private static SecretKey getSecretKey() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null, null);

    final KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) keyStore
                .getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    if (secretKeyEntry != null) {
        return secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
    }

    final KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator
            .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    final KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .build();

    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    SecretKey k = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    return getSecretKey();
}
```